# Vhdl- Counter has latch(es)

Tags: counter, vhdl

I'm just trying to count how many times the button is pressed. I tried two ways but both of them have latch(es) for "Cnt_But", and "Current_state" signals.

The problem is "IF(Button_db_s='1' and Button_db_ff_s='0')Then" line. But, that line allows me to count only once under "Rising_edge(Clock)" condition.

How can I do that without having a latch?

1)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity Tim3 is
Port(
Clock: in std_logic;
Reset: in std_logic;
Button: in std_logic
);
END Tim3;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Architecture Tim3_a of Tim3 is
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Signal Button_db_s, Button_db_ff_s : std_logic:='0';
Signal Cnt_But : integer range 0 to 5 :=0;
BEGIN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCESS(Clock, Reset)
BEGIN
    IF(Reset='1')Then
        Cnt_But<=0;
    ELSIF(Rising_Edge(Clock))Then   
        IF(Button_db_s='1' and Button_db_ff_s='0')Then      
            Cnt_But<=Cnt_But+1;
        END IF;
    END IF;         
END PROCESS;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCESS(Clock,Reset) -- Button_db Flip Flop
BEGIN
    IF(Reset='1')Then
        button_db_ff_s<='0';
    ELSIF(Rising_Edge(Clock))Then
        button_db_ff_s<=button_db_s;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Tim3_a;
```

2)

```
PROCESS(Clock, Reset)
BEGIN
    IF(Reset='1')Then
        Cnt_But<=0;
        Current_state<=Zero;
    ELSIF(Rising_Edge(Clock))Then
            IF(Button_db_s='1' and Button_db_ff_s='0')Then
                Case current_state is
                    When Zero =>
                        IF(Button_db_s='1')Then
                            current_state<=One;
                            Cnt_But<=1;
                        ELSE
                            current_state<=Zero;
                            Cnt_But<=0;
                        END IF;

                    When One =>
                        IF(Button_db_s='1')Then
                            current_state<=Two;
                            Cnt_But<=2;
                        ELSE
                            current_state<=One;
                            Cnt_But<=1;
                        END IF;

                    When Two =>
                        IF(Button_db_s='1')Then
                            current_state<=Three;
                            Cnt_But<=3;
                        ELSE
                            current_state<=Two;
                            Cnt_But<=2;
                        END IF;

                    When Three =>
                        IF(Button_db_s='1')Then
                            current_state<=Four;
                            Cnt_But<=4;
                        ELSE
                            current_state<=Three;
                            Cnt_But<=3;
                        END IF;

                    When Four =>
                        IF(Button_db_s='1')Then
                            Current_state<=Zero;
                            Cnt_But<=5;
                            Error_2_s<='1'; -- Press only 4 times.
                        ELSE
                            Current_state<=Four;
                            Cnt_But<=4;
                        END IF;
                END CASE;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;         
END PROCESS;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you actually use the button input?  I see the button_db_ff_s get assigned to button_db_s out of reset but I don't see button_db_s ever being assigned.

Comment: I'm gonna use it in a component which will give me the output signal button_db_s(debounced). I just wanted to see if my code works as I wanted, before things get complicated. Is that the problem?

Comment: If you are synthesizing, most synthesis tools will see that and notice that it's not assigned to anything and optimize it out, which in turn optimizes higher level stuff out.  Based on (1) nothing gets synthesized since button_db_s is always '0' which makes button_db_ff_s always '0' which makes the "if" statement always false which in makes Cnt_But always 0.

Comment: Thank you sir for your explanation. I changed the code and don't have any latches now.

Comment: What were you thinking when typing the second code sample? "when one, when two, when three..." What will you do if your design needs to count to one hundred, or to one million?

Comment: I just wanted to see if that method gave me latches also.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, in the first code you have no driver (yet) for Button_db_s.

In the second code, there are also problems. For example, you assign Cnt_But=5 when you move from state Four to state Zero, then you immediately overwrite this value with Cnt_But=0 in state Zero. Anyway, you are neglecting the most important phase when designing a circuit using the finite state machine (FSM) approach, which is to sketch a detailed state diagram for it. I've included a possible solution below.

[image]

Note, however, the following.

- You said that the debouncer is provided by another circuit, so that is the case (for the signal called *button*) in the FSM above, but the debouncer COULD be embedded in this machine.
- Also, it is assumed that the counter counts from 0 up to a maximum value then returns to zero automatically (which is fine for regular modulo-2**N binary counters, where N is the counter's number of FFs).
- Note that this is a *recursive* machine (the output, *cnt*, is recursive). This kind of FSM is treated in detail in chapter 11 of reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXGPo.jpg) below. Good debouncers, on the other hand, are timed (instead of recursive) circuits; timed FSMs are also treated in detail in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXGPo.jpg), in chapter 8.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXGPo.jpg) V. A. Pedroni, *Finite State Machines in Hardware: Theory and Design (with VHDL and SystemVerilog)*, MIT Press, Dec. 2013.